# Does Netbeans support vs-doc syntax for providing Javascript intellisense?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, ide, netbeans, intellisense

I've been documenting my Javascript with v-doc comments, as this works really nicely with Visual Studio.

I'm considering giving NetBeans a go, as it apparently has very nice intellisense/code completion.

Will NetBeans support vs-doc comments?

If not, then by what means does NetBeans provide intellisense for Javascript files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does, so long as you are using 6.8 and/or above.  I don't use vsdoc comments in my code, but I know that I can drop [jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js) into my project and get code completion for all of jquery.  You might take a look at the following posts and also the jquery-vsdoc to make sure all the commenting you use is supported.

[How can I get jQuery code completion in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604557/how-can-i-get-jquery-code-completion-in-netbeans)
[Netbeans.org doc on using jquery](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/js-toolkits-jquery.html)