# Jquery is not recognized on netbeans

Tags: javascript, jquery, netbeans

Please i need help i am trying to set up my computer to work on a new project and the netbeans is not recognizing any of the .js files how can i enable it to start recognize .js files.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Click Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous.
2. Click the Javascript tab, select the minimal version.
3. Add the jquery js file to your project so netbeans would be able to parse it and to properly add code completion.

Duplicate: [How can I get jQuery code completion in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604557/how-can-i-get-jquery-code-completion-in-netbeans)

Comment: again there is no javascript tab

Comment: What version of netbeans are you running?