# jQuery code hinting and syntax highlighting

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, netbeans, syntax-highlighting

When we work with Java programming language, IDEs like Netbeans and Eclipse give excellent support for code hinting and syntax highlighting ect. But how to get the same support when doing jQuery coding (in a Java project)?

Comment: For eclipse look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351847/aptana-plugin-for-eclipse-and-jquery-code-assist).

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604557/how-can-i-get-jquery-code-completion-in-netbeans)? I haven't looked at it, as I'm an Eclipse user as well. If you're happy with these solutions tell me and I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) for example. it can be installed as a plugin for eclipse and support various Javascript frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

[Amateras HTML Editor Plugin](http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=EclipseHTMLEditor) **for eclipse**.

- HTML / CSS / JavaScript Hilighting.
- JavaScript code completion, outline and validation.
- you can add any JS Libraries. and many other features

Just download the plugin, put the jar file in ECLIPSE_HOME/dropins.

Add JQuery or any JS libraries from Project's properties window (Project -> Properties)

[**see the image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCdRU.png)