# Netbeans 7 - jquery code completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, netbeans, code-completion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get jQuery code completion in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604557/how-can-i-get-jquery-code-completion-in-netbeans)

I can still get javascript code completion, but not jquery.

Ive tried

1) referencing the jquery library from google cdn

2) downloading the non-minified version of jquery into my projects folder and linking.

No matter what I try it's not working. Am I missing some sort of plugin?

EDIT: okay I figured out the problem but it seems to be some sort of a bug... the only way I can get code completion to work is to start with jQuery and not the $. Anyone know a solution?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1606999/368070 and this http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/js-toolkits-jquery.html

Comment: Thanks it's working now. I just wish there was a way to have code completion without downloading jquery to the local disk because it's better to use the google cdn anyways.

Comment: I don't know what platform you're working on but there should be a way to output a different `<script..` tag based on _debug_ or _release_. So for production you could switch to google CDN.

Comment: I think its will be able when you open a new web project, I hope I can find way to enable it on standalone html file.