# JQuery-Mobile code assist (code (auto) completion, code hinting) for Netbeans IDE

Tags: javascript, netbeans, jquery-mobile, code-completion, code-hinting

is there any code assist (code completion, code hinting) feature or plugin for the Netbeans IDE (not autocomletion for text input fields such as for names or states but a code assist (!) for coding)?

As far as I know only Dreamweaver CS5.5 supports this so far.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get jQuery code completion in NetBeans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604557/how-can-i-get-jquery-code-completion-in-netbeans)

Comment: no, it's not. Including the jquery-mobile.js file to the html file does not add the code assist functionality. It does work for jquery or jqueryui though.

Comment: I followed the instructions on the Netbeans site adding jquery-mobile-x.x.x.js on http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/js-toolkits-jquery.html#addingjquery.  Including the jquery-mobile.js file to the html file does not add the code assist functionality. It does work for jquery (and maybe for jquery-ui (not tested)) though. I think it has to be implemented into the Netbeans IDE because also such html attributes like "data-role","data-theme" in div tags have to be supported, too and not only the javascript functions. But not even those are supported or is there a trick do make it work?

Comment: Did you use the non-minified version?

Comment: awesome! Now it works better, I get class values like "ui-btn-right" completed but why it doesn't support completion for data-role or data-theme ? Also in javascript there is no completion for the .live() function for example - what could be the reason?

Comment: I've never used Netbeans and I've never tried to hook-up auto-complete in any IDE, so... I dunno :). I just figured that if the application is going to parse a script to get function names then you should give it a file with function names rather than the minified version.

Comment: Thank you! Your second comment could be marked as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured we could drop the un-answered rate a bit here:

If the application (Netbeans) is going to parse a script to get function names then you should give it a file with function names rather than the [minified](http://www.google.com/webhp?q=define%3aminified)/[obfuscated](http://www.google.com/webhp?q=define%3aobfuscated) version.