# Code completion for jquery mobile in NetBeans IDE?

Tags: jquery-mobile, autocomplete, netbeans-7

After including full jquery.js in the projects web root the auto completion for jquery seems to work (e.g. it suggests several options like onclick etc. when I type "on"), but it does not suggest me any data-roles when I start to type "da" and then press ctrl+space. So the question is: is it possible to achieve the code completion for the jquery mobile within the NetBeans IDE 7.4 and if it is, how should I do it? Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery-Mobile code assist (code (auto) completion, code hinting) for Netbeans IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267603/jquery-mobile-code-assist-code-auto-completion-code-hinting-for-netbeans-id)