# Jquery code completion on NetBeans

Tags: jquery, netbeans, autocomplete

I tried looking everywhere for a way to get this working, though even here I could not find a working method to make the jquery code completion to work on NetBeans 7.2.1.

I would appreciate if someone could give me a definitive way to get this to work.

Comment: I have NetBeans IDE 7.2 (Build 201207171143) and jquery auto complete is working fine.

Comment: I have autocomplete, but a lot of methods are missing. http://i.imgur.com/Sid0D.png

As you can see "fadeIn" and "fadeOut" are missing, for example.

Comment: It is also works fine for me: http://imgur.com/ypFc8

Comment: Can you describe what you did to make the methods be listen?

All I did was to create a "js" folder on my project and add the "jquery-1.8.3" there.

Comment: It is just CakePHP project and the image is a screen shot from a ctp file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get jQuery code completion in NetBeans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604557/how-can-i-get-jquery-code-completion-in-netbeans)

Comment: No, that method doesn't work.